Does increase of effective compression ratio increase thermal efficiency?
Does increase of effective compression ratio increase thermal efficiency of turbo engine or efficiency only depend on static compression ratio? Is high effective compression ratio reason why turbo engine has higher thermal efficiency then NA engine?
Please explain using  Otto cycle, how temperature T1,T2,T3,T4 are different at turbo vs NA engine.

Increasing the compression ratio raises the temperature at which heat is added to the working fluid in an Otto cycle engine. This raises its carnot efficiency.
Supercharging the air ## Heading ##inlet to an Otto cycle engine increases the mass flow rate at which fuel can be burned in it, which increases its power output.
Specifically, turbocharging the inlet recovers waste energy from the exhaust stream of the engine and uses it to supercharge the engine, which increases the both the overall thermodynamic efficiency and the power output of the engine.

The short answer is yes.
Staging the compression and expansion lets you get to a higher total compression (without detonation or melting stuff) via intercooling. That raises the maximum thermal efficiency that can be had. Exploiting that theoretical improvement is the fun part because intercooling involves removing heat from a heat engine. But less will get lost in jacket water and out the tailpipe.

so higher boost get higher thermal efficiency?

@22flower so higher boost get higher volumetric efficiency
